# Cannot cast from EditText to Button

Tags: java, android

I've readed a lot of posts about this but didn't helped me. I've tried with `clean` and `re-build` the project but also didn't helped me. I don't really understand what mean this error. Can someone help with solving this error?

`RegisterActivity.java`

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import library.DatabaseHandler;
import library.UserFunctions;

public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
Button buttonRegister;
Button buttonLinkToLogin;
EditText inputFullName;
EditText inputEmail;
EditText inputPassword;
TextView registerErrorMsg;

// JSON Response node names
private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
    inputFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerName);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerEmail);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerPassword);
    buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);
    buttonLinkToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLinkToLoginScreen);
    registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_error);

    // Register Button Click event
    buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(RegisterActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Registering...");
            RegisterTask registerTask = new RegisterTask(RegisterActivity.this, progressDialog);
            registerTask.execute();
        }
    });

    // Link to Login Screen
    buttonLinkToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            // Close Registration View
            finish();
        }
    });
}

public void registerReport(Integer responseCode) {
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    if (responseCode == 0) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Register Error", duration);
        toast.show();
    }
    else {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Register Success", duration);
        toast.show();
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                DashboardActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }



}

public EditText findViewById(int registeremail) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

And the lines are this

```
buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);
buttonLinkToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLinkToLoginScreen);
```

Register.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#3b3b3b" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip" >
    <!--  View Title Label -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        android:text="REGISTER"
        android:textSize="25dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <!--  Name Label -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Full Name" />
    <!--  Name TextField -->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/registerName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:singleLine="true"/>

    <!--  Email Label -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Email" />
    <!--  Email TextField -->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/registerEmail"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:singleLine="true"/>

    <!--  Password Label -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:text="Password" />
    <!--  Password TextField -->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/registerPassword"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:password="true" 
        android:singleLine="true"/>


    <!--  Error message -->
    <TextView android:id="@+id/register_error"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#e30000"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <!--  Login Button -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonRegister"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:text="Register" />

    <!--  Link to Login Screen -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLinkToLoginScreen"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="Already registred. Login Me!"
        android:textColor="#21dbd4"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

update

```
Button buttonRegister;
Button buttonLinkToLogin;
```

I can see in console output this

```
res\layout\register.xml:75: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@id/buttonLinkToLoginScreen').
res\layout\register.xml:67: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@id/buttonRegister').
```

Comment: have you any demo which i can test for you. also add complete stacktrace

Comment: I can't runnit because say the project has errors.. and the errors are this 2 lines.

Comment: Are you sure you are inflating Register.xml view file you provided? Copy and paste a full error stacktrace in your question so we could see some more details.

Comment: Please put your buttonRegister and buttonLinkToLogin definitions.

Comment: This definition? This is in `RegisterActivity.java` where are they.

Comment: @Ivan look, at my answer. The definition is the line where you define your fields. In your case it is for example: `EditText inputFullName`

Comment: But why no resource found when they are there?

Comment: if shareable the provide me link of pro. i also think @kklys soln might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you declared your two buttons as `TextFields`, not `Buttons`. That is why it says that project has errors and cannot even be runned. If it runs and then throws errors, that it cannot cast, problem would be elswere.

I suppose you copy-pasted controls declarations and forgot to change their types.

**UPDATE**

Why are you overriding `findViewById` method? get rid of it. As you can see you are overriding default method which would return correct object. Your method returns wrong object (`TextField`) - that is why it says that it cannot cast from `TextField` to `Button`, and it is `null` if that was not enough.

Comment: Provide fields `declarations`. If your problem is in java code, and you don't know what declarations are, just give us full code of your java class.

Comment: @kklys is right, there is no need to override the findViewById method. It causes the problem. Remove it and it will work.

Comment: I din't know when this is generated. Is auto generated. And yes this was the problem. Thank's for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Three probable solutions;

- Try all lowercase letters in ID's in XML file
- Restart Eclipse
- No errors should remain on res directory, otherwise it cannot recognize ID's, so clear if any red marks

These often solve such kind of problems.

Comment: Tried with lowercase no effect. Also restarted Eclipse and same. The red marks are in `src` in `res` i don't have any.

Comment: again... provide us with your fields `declarations`

Comment: I tested this with ony buttonRegister and buttonLinkToLogin and it works fine. Haven't you included xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
in your parent LinearLayout?